# how to append choice list items in existing choice list in filenet p8 4.5.1 api

Tags: java, filenet

I need some help using the **File Net API.**
I have a choice list called Country with choices `IND`,`USA` etc...

I have to append one more choice list called state with choice items as Chennai,Delhi etc..

but I couldn't find any API for appending or adding choice list items   using FILE NET API

This is the code which I tried:

```
ChoiceList objChoiceListStr = Factory.ChoiceList.getInstance(objectstore,id);
objChoiceListStr.set_ChoiceValues(Factory.Choice.createList());
objChoiceListStr.get_ChoiceValues().add(choiceString);
```

Please help.

Comment: A code snippet can be found on the FileNet documentation website: [FileNet 4.5 infocenter](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSNW2F_4.5.1/com.ibm.p8.doc/developer_help/content_engine_api/guide/choicelist_procedures.htm%23creating_a_choice_list)

Comment: if i understand your question, i think u need to make dependant choice list, one that says the country and a dependant choice that loads only the states of that country. there is no way to do that natively in FileNet, you need to build a custom UI and use your own database to control the fileds. I think in Content Navigator it can be done due to its compatibility with EDS (External Data Services: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEUEX_2.0.2/com.ibm.developingeuc.doc/eucap001.dita).